# Feeling like a bad learner with Fibonacci sequence

Tags: python-3.x, fibonacci

I should start by saying I’m a noob at this. I just started learning Python 3 three weeks ago.
I’m using [Codio](https://codio.com) and trying to print out the Fibonacci sequence from 0 through 21. If someone could help me find a solution for this I’d be so grateful! I’ve been stuck on this for a while.

Here is my code:

```py
import sys

N = int(sys.argv[1])

n1, n2 = 0, 1
while n2 < 22:
    print(n2)
    n1, n2 = n2, n1 + n2
```

I’m using `python3` to run this script, if that helps. Thank you guys in advance! I don’t really like asking for help often, but I’m lost. I’ve rewrote my code a few times and still end up with an error, am I just a bad beginner?

Comment: If you want your code to print from `0 to 21`, use `n1<22` and `print(n1)` instead of checking and printing `n2`.

Comment: How are you running it?   I typed `python3 x.py 99`, and it didn't complain; but If I type `python3 x.py` I get complaints of index out of range on `int(sys.argv[1])` because I didn't provide an argument to it.

Comment: Which error do you get, and on which line do you get it?

Comment: I get this weird error "Program Failed for Input: 0", I'll keep trying though

Answer (score 0):

For `Fibonacci`, there is a popular formula known as [Binet's Formula](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Binet%27s_Formula), which states the counting the fibonnaci till `n` numbers. The formula is:

[image: Binet's Formula]

So, making use of the formula, you can take the input of `n` here, which is the end, in your case: `21`

```
import math

def fibonacci(n):
  outer_number = 1 / pow(5, 1/2) 
  first_computation = ((1 + pow(5, 1/2)) / 2)
  second_computation = ((1 - pow(5, 1/2)) / 2)
  
  return outer_number * (pow(first_computation, n) - pow(second_computation, n))
  
print(int(fibonacci(21))) # >>> 10946
```

Answer (score 0):

The Fibonacci sequence is a sequence of integers where each element is the sum of the two previous elements.

I don't know how to code with python but I did solve this problem using C#:

```
static int fibonacci(int n)
    {
        if (n == 1)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        if (n == 2)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
        }
    }
```

You can solve this problem using a recursive function. If the numer of the sequence requested is the first you can easily return 0, or 1 if it's the second. If not, you will return the sum of the results of this function with the two previous numbers. Assuming n is the request, then you'll need to reexecute this function with n - 1 and n - 2, this will create a loop that continues until n - 1 = 2 and n - 2 = 1

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer in python3 is like follows:

```
n0=0
n1=1
print(n0)
print(n1)
while True:
    n=n0+n1
    n0=n1
    n1=n
    print(n)
    if n>=21:
        break
```

Make sure the indentations are correct since that is how python identifies the end of a block of statements.